# Sencha ExtJs Why Return `this` from `constructor` method?

Tags: javascript, extjs, constructor, return, this

Sencha Touch v2.3, ExtJS v4.1.0.

When creating a new class, why is it necessary to return `this` from the `constructor` method?

Example (from link below):

```
var Person = new Ext.Class({
    name: 'Mr. Unknown',

    constructor: function(name) {
        this.name = name;

        return this; // <-- HERE. Why????
    },

    walk: function(steps) {
        alert(this.name + ' is walking ' + steps + ' steps');
    }
});

var jacky = new Person('Jacky');
jacky.walk(10); // alerts "Jacky is walking 10 steps"
```

http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-class-system

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is necessary, but it does make the code easier to understand as to what will happen when the constructor returns: Your newly created object will be returned to the caller. This code sample will still work even without `return this;`.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `this` is different than using the `new` keyword to produce an object.  The `this` returned by the person function will always reference the same object.  In most cases this is going to be the global object, but, like any function, depends on the context in which it is called.

For example, take:

```
   function person(name) {
        this.name = name;

        return this; 
    }
```

Say you create a new person by invoking the function, which returns `this`:

```
 var newPerson = person("Bob");
```

And you do it again.

```
var evenNewerPerson = person("Frank");

newPerson.name === "Frank" => true 
evenNewerPerson === newPerson => true
```

Thus you are pointing to the same object.  Whereas using the `new` keyword will create a completely new object.

```
var somePerson = new Person("Sue");
var otherPerson = new Person("Sally");

somePerson === otherPerson => false
```